# Remove 'scroll up' script on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code in my < head > tags which fades a button in when the window is 150px from the bottom.

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 150)) {
    $("#up-btn").fadeIn(500);
} else {
    $("#up-btn").fadeOut(500);
}
});
</script>
```

the css

```
#up-btn {
position: fixed;
display: none;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
bottom: -4px; right: 3%;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #1aa97f;
padding: 18px 20px; margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
}
```

html

```
<footer>
  <a id="up-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();">TOP <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
</footer>
```

I want the #up-btn to remain 'disappeared/gone' on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your javascript code like this

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 150)) {
    $("#up-btn").fadeIn(500);
        } else {
    $("#up-btn").fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
};
```

Now you can change  '768' to the the lowest device with you want your script to work.  The code above basicly stops your script from running until it has hit an ipad format.

Comment: it removes functionality on all screen sizes

Comment: That seems strange, since i've been using the piece of code for multiple project with succes. Could you tell me more about any errors, or anything that could shine some more light on the matter?

Comment: using it as I have put in has it fade in and out when it's screen size. Adding your code to the beginning/end it does not show up at all

Comment: Have you tried putting your script in a separate file?

Comment: yes same result. SOmething just happens when I add 'if ($(window).width() > 768) { ...' Removing the ; on the second last line it works, but in both mobile and screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) in Javascript as the equivalent of CSS media queries, which gives you a way to see if the screen is mobile size.

Example (from MDN):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```